# Replace a word inside a third-party Actionscript Flash file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Sir, I am talking about a chat website's Flash skin, in that skin there is a user-list and I want to replace any text of "`src`" to a word "`attacker`" so that it will be prevented from html execution.

For further advice should I provide code of whole **videochat.fla** or just **userlist.as** inside **videochat.fla**?

Here is the code of **userlist.as**: https://pastebin.com/vVifkVZ5

Below is the image of chat userlist which I am talking about where if any user update his status message which show in front of usernames in **`User`** list then the word `src` should automatically replaced by `attacker`.

[image]

Comment: PS: If you move the mouse over "down" arrow you will see the reason for down-votes. _`"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"`_. Always say what you've tried or where you suspect the problem exists. Forum respects some effort to help yourself as **programmer** (eg: problem solver).

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at your code it seems `function onJoin()` has user-names for adding to the user-list. Maybe try editing the name at that point?

```
public function onJoin(result:Object)
{

    //* result values:
    //* result["username"]
    //* result["room"]
    //* result["profile"]


    //# edit the user-name

    if  ( result["username"].indexOf("src") >=  0 )
    {
        result["username"] = result["username"].replace("src", "attacker");
    }

    //# do rest of code

    if (!user_exists(result["username"]))
    {
        addUser(result["username"],result["profile"]);
    }
    else
    {
        changeUser(result["username"],result["profile"]);
        }
        if (result["profile"]["invisible"] !=  true )
        {
            this["memberlist"].onJoin(result["username"]);
        }
        loadWidgets();

    }

}
```